# How to reduce the number of click events with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a table with 100s of rows and each row has its own click event:

```
$('#scorecard-table tbody > tr.accordion').on('click', function (event) {}
```

I want to get this down to one click event, I thought this would do it?

```
$('#scorecard-table').on('click', 'tbody > tr.accordion', function (event) {}
```

I assumed this would assign a single click event on the table itself instead of an event per row?

The second version seems to have just as many events as the first version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want the click to do... open/close accordion ?

Comment: In the click handler do you need to know the clicked row/cell?

Comment: How or where do you count the event listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following explanation on jquery

http://api.jquery.com/on/

In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

That should answer your question?

Comment: This is what I thought but in my scenario I still get 100s of click events, maybe it's just the FireFox plugin I'm using is showing them as individual click events when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do here... if you're wanting to do the entire table (just the one event) why not just do:

```
$('#scorecard-table').on('click', function (event) {}
```

Doing it this way, though, you wouldn't be able to detect which row was clicked unless you fiddled about with the mouseX / mouseY. You're best off with the singular click events like you have now.

Comment: You can use the event Object to know where the user clicked, see my answer.

Comment: Good stuff, well thought of :)

Answer (score 0):

The `second` one is `fast` as tested on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com)

```
$('#scorecard-table').on('click', 'tbody > tr.accordion', function(event) {
   // your code
});
```

As above will selects `$('#scorecard-table')` first then bind `click event` to `tbody > tr.accordion`

And in the **first-one**

`$("#scorecard-table tbody > tr.accordion")` evaluates from **right to left** - i.e. first it finds all of the `tr.accordion rows` in the page and then narrows it down to those under `#scorecard-table tbody`

Here you can [test the performance](http://jsperf.com/rohankumar-on-click-tr)

Read [Efficient-jquery-selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/) and see [performance of child selectors](http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener only to the table, and check if the user clicked on a row. (It will work even if you add more rows dinamically)

```
$('#myTable').on("click", function (e) {

    if(e.target.tagName == "TD"){
        alert(e.target.parentNode.id);

        // if you want the jQuery row object
        // var rowClicked = $(e.target.parentNode)
    }
});
```

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/utVzx/2/